# Why does Router Event throws only scroll event post angular update from 13 to 15.2.9

Tags: router, angular15, angular-upgrade, angular-router-events

I upgraded the angular version from 13 to 15.2.9 and I observed is the Router Functionality is breaking. The Router Event is only throwing SCROLL EVENT Instead Navigation End. Please suggest where am I missing something or how to fix the routing issue.

The Scroll Event is appearing as **scroll(anchor:'null',position:'null')** .

I need the complete router event to trigger and at last Navigation End to appear so that I can capture it in my component.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue (with Angular 17), for me, it was a rookie mistake.

So like you, I was just getting the `Scroll` event and could not understand why.

It turns out that for my case, it's because I had placed the code to listen to router event within `ngOnInit()` of my component.

So by the time this code was run, all the other event from the router where already thrown.

**The solution was to move the code to the constructor of my component.**

Answer (score 1):

I have been getting the same problem after updating from Angular 13 to 15.
This is my workaround:

```
this.router.events
  .pipe(
    filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd || (event instanceof Scroll && event.routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd)),
    map((event) => event instanceof Scroll ? event.routerEvent as NavigationEnd : event as NavigationEnd),
  )
```